# Why does Thread.join use currentTimeMillis?

Tags: java, multithreading

In Java, there are two ways of accessing time, System.currentTimeMillis and System.nanoTime.  The first is similar to a wall clock, and can change time based on leap seconds, and other OS caused time changes.  Because of this, measuring durations of time is better suited to use `nanoTime` which is more accurate and usually more precise.

With that in mind, why does `Thread.join()` use the currentTimeMillis instead of nanoTime?

The code in question is:

```
    public final synchronized void join(long millis) throws InterruptedException {
    long base = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long now = 0;

    if (millis < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("timeout value is negative");
    }

    if (millis == 0) {
        while (isAlive()) {
            wait(0);
        }
    } else {
        while (isAlive()) {
            long delay = millis - now;
            if (delay <= 0) {
                break;
            }
            wait(delay);
            now = System.currentTimeMillis() - base;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because **caller(s)** expect it to timeout like "a wall clock".

Comment: Because `join()` is @since 1.0 and `nanoTime()`isn't, and changing the behaviour would have been poor practice.

Comment: Changing error prone behavior to less error prone is a valid though.  Regardless of when join() was added, it can be reimplemented at any version.

Comment: @eliott Really? If you write wait(1h) you expect the code to return immediately once a year? Honestly it's annoying behaviour (and runs counter to what "wait an hour" means colloquially) but that's how it's specified and since the problem comes up exceedingly rarely it's not a big problem in practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually is a bug, and was reported in [JDK-8098798](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8098798) and [JDK-8200284](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8200284).   It has been [fixed](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk12/rev/13d6be5fbfa5) in JDK 12.